# Use Collate in CONCAT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, concatenation, collate

I was trying to concatonate 2 columns with a whitespace in between and got a collation error:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.PERSON_ID,
    p.ID_NUMBER,
    CONCAT(p.FULLNAMES, CONCAT(' ', p.SURNAME)) AS NAME,
    o.ORG_NAME,
    w.WARD_DESCRIPTION AS WARD,
    ess.DESCRIPTION AS SECTOR
```

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the concat operation

The collation of both the offending columns in my database is: `Latin1_General_CI_AS`

So then I was trying to collate the whitespace to this collation, but I have no idea how to do this. My attempt:

```
CONCAT(p.FULLNAMES, (CONCAT((COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS = ' '), p.SURNAME))) AS NAME,
```

or something?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You put the COLLATE after each field, viz in the worst case scenario:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CONCAT(p.FULLNAMES COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, 
      (CONCAT(' ' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, 
          p.SURNAME COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS))) AS NAME
FROM Person p
```

Comment: You can probably avoid collating the literal by collating via DATABASE_DEFAULT, viz `SELECT DISTINCT
    CONCAT(p.FULLNAMES COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT, 
      (CONCAT(' ', p.SURNAME COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT))) AS NAME
FROM Person p`

Comment: @StuartLC that could mess up your <order by>. It is better to change the space to the same collation as the other columns

Answer (score 5):

This will fix your problem:

```
SELECT CONCAT(p.FULLNAMES,' ' collate Latin1_General_CI_AS,p.SURNAME) AS NAME
```

The space is getting same default collation as the database, therefore it has to have same collation as your columns. Kind of silly in my opinion

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this problem by simply using the concat operator:

```
p.FULLNAMES + ' ' + p.SURNAME
```